# Extracting rounding parameters from a set of float values

Tags: ruby, crystal-lang, floating-point-conversion

Given the following float values :

```
n00.0, n0.0, n.0, 0.n, 0.0n, 0.00n, 0.000n
```

where n can be 1, 2 or 5, what is the smartest and fastest way to extract the corresponding integer values, to be used as rounding parameters

```
-2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4
```

At the moment, I am using a hash table : fast, but not so smart, I think!

Comment: I currently use Crystal-Lang (or Ruby).
Float value at the moment, but could be a string.

Comment: The implementation of `Number#humanize` should give some inspiration: https://github.com/crystal-lang/crystal/blob/5999ae29beacf4cfd54e232ca83c1a46b79f26a5/src/humanize.cr#L179-L223

Comment: `-Math.log10(value).floor` did the trick !
More than 60 times faster than hash.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I thought using a hash was a good approach and was skeptical that it would be outperformed by `-Math.log10(k).floor`, so I ran the following benchmark.

*Construct the hash*

```
h = { 100.0=>-2, 10.0=>-1, 1.0=>0, 0.1=>1, 0.01=>2,
      200.0=>-2, 20.0=>-1, 2.0=>0, 0.2=>1, 0.02=>2,
      500.0=>-2, 50.0=>-1, 5.0=>0, 0.5=>1, 0.05=>2 }
```

*Construct test array for benchmark (15 million elements)*

```
n = 1_000_000
(arr = h.keys.flat_map { |k| [k]*n }.shuffle).size
  #=> 15_000_000 
arr.first(10)
  #=> [20.0, 0.02, 5.0, 0.5, 0.02, 0.05, 500.0, 50.0, 50.0, 20.0] 
arr.last(10)
  #=> [500.0, 0.5, 0.1, 20.0, 0.01, 0.1, 500.0, 50.0, 0.05, 0.5]
```

*Perform benchmark*

```
require 'fruity'

compare(
  hash:  -> { arr.each { |k| h[k] } },
  log10: -> { arr.each { |k| -Math.log10(k).floor } }
)
Running each test once. Test will take about 42 seconds.
hash is faster than log10 by 60.0% ± 10.0%
```

Comment: Ported your benchmark to Crystal and there the hash is seemingly 4x slower still, but I'm not 100% confident I tricked LLVM out of all code elimination (the most naive port has it realize the result of the log10 operation is never read and just eliminates it entirely, which is probably where the 60x comment came from).

Comment: Note the question is tagged with crystal-lang, too. Crystal is a programming language implemented as an [LLVM](https://llvm.org/) frontend, see https://crystal-lang.org/